# Sitemap XML for Wordpress

Tags: xml, sitemap

I want to create sitemap.xml on wordpress. How to create sitemap.xml like this:

```
    <urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 

    http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"><url><loc>

    http://kody.com.ua/</loc><lastmod>2016-10-08</lastmod>

    <changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url><url><loc>

    http://kody.com.ua/promokod-uber</loc><lastmod>2016-10-08</lastmod>

    <changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.9</priority></url>

     ................
```

But not like this:

```
https://www.famethemes.com/sitemap-misc.xml 2017-09-01 08:17

https://www.famethemes.com/sitemap-pt-download-2017-09.xml  2017-09-01 08:17

https://www.famethemes.com/sitemap-pt-download-2017-08.xml  2017-09-01 07:27

https://www.famethemes.com/sitemap-pt-download-2017-04.xml  2017-04-18 03:07
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use **[Google XML Sitemap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/)**? It does the job for you, and has over 2 million installs.

You can download it [**here**](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/google-sitemap-generator.4.0.9.zip), and to install it you upload it via FTP, or use the `Add Plugin` function of WordPress. You then activate it through the plugin configuration page under `Settings -> XML-Sitemap`.

From there you can customise settings like priorities and change frequencies.